# How to make it easier to deploy my Jar to Spark Cluster in standalone mode?

Tags: jar, apache-spark

I have a small cluster with 3 machines, and another machine for developing and testing. When developing, I set `SparkContext` to `local`. When everything is OK, I want to deploy the Jar file I build to every node. Basically I manually move this jar to cluster and copy to HDFS which shared by the cluster. Then I could change the code to:

```
//standalone mode
val sc = new SparkContext(
     "spark://mymaster:7077", 
     "Simple App", 
     "/opt/spark-0.9.1-bin-cdh4",   //spark home
     List("hdfs://namenode:8020/runnableJars/SimplyApp.jar") //jar location
)
```

to run it in my IDE. My question: Is there any way easier to move this jar to cluster?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Spark, the program creating the SparkContext is called 'the driver'. It's sufficient that the jar file with your job is available to the local file system of the driver in order for it to pick it up and ship it to the master/workers.

In concrete, your config will look like:

```
//favor using Spark Conf to configure your Spark Context
val conf = new SparkConf()
             .setMaster("spark://mymaster:7077")
             .setAppName("SimpleApp")
             .set("spark.local.ip", "172.17.0.1")
             .setJars(Array("/local/dir/SimplyApp.jar"))

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Under the hood, the driver will start a server where the workers will download the jar file(s) from the driver. It's therefore important (and often an issue) that the workers have network access to the driver.  This can often be ensured by setting 'spark.local.ip' on the driver in a network that's accessible/routable from the workers.

Comment: You can also use `SparkContext.jarOfClass(this.getClass)` instead of hard-coding it `Array("/local/dir/SimplyApp.jar")`.

Comment: @samthebest that method determines the jar from which the provided class has been loaded and works fine for dependencies but might not work for the driver class which in an IDE will not have been loaded from a JAR.  The easiest is to build an uberjar with Maven Shade or SBT assembly and provide that as unique dependency.

Comment: Just FWIW this answer depends on accepting the default setting for --deploy-mode which is client, if you are using --deploy-mode cluster then you don't know which worker node the driver will run on, so therefore you do need these jars visible to all workers, per Advanced Dependency Management it's a good idea anyway because it reduces network traffic. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management. Also the jars are not shipped to the master as the master doesn't deal with code, just scheduling of code aka "applications" in Spark