# How do you submit a job to Spark from code?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I've spun up a single-node standalone Spark cluster and confirmed my build works with `./bin/run-example SparkPi 10`. Then I wrote a really simple test project in scala;

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    val sc = new SparkContext("spark://UbuntuVM:7077", "Simple Application")

    val count = sc.parallelize(1 to 100).map{i =>
      val x = Math.random()
      val y = Math.random()
      if (x*x + y*y < 1) 1 else 0
    }.reduce(_ + _)
    println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / 100)
  }
}
```

I'm running this from inside my IDE (IntelliJ). It connects to the cluster successfully, and I see it submit jobs, but they all throw an error;

```
INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 7) on executor 192.168.1.233: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (Main$$anonfun$1) [duplicate 7]
```

If I understand spark correctly, this is because the cluster can't find the code. So how do I feed the code to spark? I'm not running HDFS or anything in this test, but it's all on one box, so I would have expected SparkContext to pass the current directory to spark, but it apparently does not.

Can anyone point me at the right way to set this up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make it easier to deploy my Jar to Spark Cluster in standalone mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052899/how-to-make-it-easier-to-deploy-my-jar-to-spark-cluster-in-standalone-mode)

Comment: I actually tried sc.addJar(SparkContext.jarOfClass(this.getClass).get) -- but of course this fails, because there's no JAR.. IntelliJ isn't creating one..

Comment: sbt-assembly does work to produce a JAR i can spark-submit, but I still can't find a way to make the 'run' function in intelliJ just run the thing..

Comment: Create jar artifact configuration for your project in IntelliJ then open your run configuration and  add "build artifact" to the "before launch" section. `sc.addJar` should contain full path to your artifact. Obviously this is development setup, not intended for production usage.

Comment: So maybe I'm just blind, but I don't see a way to create a build artifact that will actually follow the sbt-assembly setup (excluding the spark stuff for example)?

Comment: 1. You can add or remove any artifact dependencies on artifact settings tab. 2. Actually, on second thought you don't need artifact at all, you can add any sbt command to the "before launch" section in your run configuration. Just add "assembly" there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test your Spark program locally, you don't even need to spin up the single-node standalone Spark. Just set your master url to `local[*]` like this

```
val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "Simple Application", sparkConf)
```

Then in sbt, type `> run` to run your program (this should be the same as running from IntelliJ, but I used to run the program from terminal using sbt).

Since you may not want to change your master url in code between `local[*]` and `spark://...` many times, you can leave them blank

```
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf())
```

and set your java properties when running, for example, in `build.sbt`, you can add

```
javaOptions := Seq("-Dspark.master=local[*]", "-Dspark.app.name=my-app")
```

and run it using `run` in sbt.

---

To make a more comprehensive local-mode experience, you may want to add the following lines in your `build.sbt`

```
run in Compile <<= Defaults.runTask(fullClasspath in Compile, mainClass in (Compile, run), runner in (Compile, run))
runMain in Compile <<= Defaults.runTask(fullClasspath in Compile, mainClass in (Compile, run), runner in (Compile, run))
fork := true
javaOptions := Seq("-Dspark.master=local[*]", s"-Dspark.app.name=my-app")
outputStrategy := Some(StdoutOutput)
```

We have created a sbt plugin which can add these settings for you, it can also help you deploy a standalone Spark cluster on cloud system like aws ec2, give a look at [spark-deployer](https://github.com/KKBOX/spark-deployer) if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a crucial step:

`org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit`

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit.scala

which actually submits a job to the cluster.  Unfortunately there is not presently a solid working wrapper for it except for `spark-submit`.  So there presently is not a reliable way to programatically submit spark jobs. There is a jira for it that was partially addressed in Feb 2015: but it lacks documentation.

```
 https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/3916/files
```

The difficulty lies in the complexity of the environmental machinations provided by `spark-submit`.  It has not been found possible to replicate them solely within scala/java code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Class.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/package-summary.html

```
    import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher;

   public class MyLauncher {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Process spark = new SparkLauncher()
         .setAppResource("/my/app.jar")
         .setMainClass("my.spark.app.Main")
         .setMaster("local")
         .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_MEMORY, "2g")
         .launch();
       spark.waitFor();
     }
   }
```