# Apache Spark cannot find class CSVReader

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-spark

My code to try and parse a simple csv file looks like this:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("word_count");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaRDD<String> csv = sc.textFile("/home/user/data.csv");

JavaRDD<String[]> parsed = csv.map(x-> new CSVReader(new StringReader(x)).readNext());
parsed.foreach(x->System.out.println(x));
```

However, Spark job ends with a class not found exception saying that `CSVReader` cannot be found. My `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Well ... Did you _provide_ the needed library at runtime?

Comment: Side note - Spark 1.1.0 is a very old version. Current version is 2.0.0.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I am not sure how to answer that. I am new to Maven. My understanding is that `provided` causes the JAR to be downloaded and shipped with the final JAR that will be created. :/

Comment: Unfortunately, not. The scope `provided` is a hint for the packaging tool (for example the maven-war-plugin or the maven-assembly-plugin, or whatever) to _not_ ship this library inside the packaged program because it will be _provided_ by the runtime environment (for example, the tomcat installation you use). For example, the Java EE API is a library that you depend on but will always be provided by the runtime. Other libraries are usually not provided, so you need to set their scope to `compile`. If that helps, I will write a short answer for that.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose correct me if I am wrong, for all external dependencies not provided by Spark runtime (eg twitter4j, GSON, etc.) I have to set the scope to `compile`, defacto?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Spark. But for this issue it seems to play the same role as a web container (like Tomcat) or a EE container (like JBoss or Wildfly). So, yes, you have to set the scope to `compile` for having it shipped with your application. Note, that this is the default scope, so simply removing the scope element is enough.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Maven Shade did it :) but my question is: is using shade considered good practice? it will increase the JAR size a lot, right? :)

Comment: Ok, the maven-shade-plugin is another packagin plugin (I already mentioned two). You maybe seem to misunderstand the role of the maven-jar-plugin. It only assembles the code in your project into a JAR file. It does not package any other code into it - esapecially code from other llibraries. An application does not consist of such a single JAR file, it consists of many of these. A packaging tool (we often use the maven-assembly-plugin) now creates such an application. The maven-shade-plugin is simply another one. Good or bad? They all have their uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If your code depends on other projects, you will need to package them
>   alongside your application in order to distribute the code to a Spark
>   cluster. To do this, create an assembly jar (or “uber” jar) containing
>   your code and its dependencies. Both sbt and Maven have assembly
>   plugins. When creating assembly jars, list Spark and Hadoop as
>   provided dependencies; these need not be bundled since they are
>   provided by the cluster manager at runtime.
>   Source: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Maven does not ship dependency JARs when it packages the project into a JAR. To ship the dependency JARs along, I added the Maven Shade plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <filters>
            <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </filter>
        </filters>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

also see: [How to make it easier to deploy my Jar to Spark Cluster in standalone mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052899/how-to-make-it-easier-to-deploy-my-jar-to-spark-cluster-in-standalone-mode)